# Why is user reputation hidden on Community Wiki questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

Whenever I am on a Community Wiki, it seems that the reputation of users is hidden. I'm running on Google Chrome Windows XP. Is this a bug? or working as intended?

Comment: Do you mean that users don't acquire reputation for their answers, or that the users actual reputation score (i.e. for you, Chacha102, this would be "181" right now)? I have a funny feeling Jerrod et al. may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: The OP marked my answer as the answer to his question. The question is clearly worded as to specify displaying the reputation, not a lack of reputation. Why is your spidey sense going off?

Comment: No, he answered it correctly. I know that we don't get reputation for CW. Just didn't expect to not see the reputation. Normally you see it for everyone everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working as intended. Community Wiki questions do not affect reputation, and therefore, the reputation is hidden. Generally, CW questions should not be something that has one and only one answer, where reputation is awarded and important.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug - as designed as I understand CW.

CW is about the question and answer content, not the rep of the people asking and answering.  Thus, one can edit others' CW questions and answers freely.  **There's even less ownership of CW content than for SO in general**.

The editors' rep is not germane, and I suppose the editors' names are displayed just to enhance the sense of community.

Comment: You should probably clarify.

Comment: @devinb: thanks for the suggestion - that was a pretty uninformative answer, wasn't it?